# Problem with CMake "Could not find cmake module file"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, cmake-language

I'm making a library that overloads the operator new and delete to save the pointer into my vector-like class. When the program ends a class object frees the memory.
I'm new to CMake.
I used CMake but I get a CMake error. In CMakeOutput.log it says:

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.18363 - AMD64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: gcc 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/3/2020 8:28:00 PM.
Project "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\3.17.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
  CMakeCCompilerId.c
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdC.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdC.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdC.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCCompilerId.obj
  CompilerIdC.vcxproj -> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\3.17.3\CompilerIdC\.\CompilerIdC.exe
PostBuildEvent:
  for %%i in (cl.exe) do @echo CMAKE_C_COMPILER=%%~$PATH:i
  :VCEnd
  CMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\CompilerIdC.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\3.17.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:05.85


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CompilerIdC.exe"

Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CompilerIdC.vcxproj"

The C compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Garbage Collector/build/CMakeFiles/3.17.3/CompilerIdC/CompilerIdC.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: g++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/3/2020 8:28:07 PM.
Project "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\3.17.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdCXX.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdCXX.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
  CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj -> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\3.17.3\CompilerIdCXX\.\CompilerIdCXX.exe
PostBuildEvent:
  for %%i in (cl.exe) do @echo CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=%%~$PATH:i
  :VCEnd
  CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\CompilerIdCXX.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\3.17.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.51


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Garbage Collector/build/CMakeFiles/3.17.3/CompilerIdCXX/CompilerIdCXX.exe"

Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Garbage Collector/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_e1916.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.26.28806 for x64

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_e1916.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_e1916.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"

  testCCompiler.c

  cmTC_e1916.vcxproj -> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_e1916.exe




Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Garbage Collector/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_68d77.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.26.28806 for x64

  CMakeCCompilerABI.c

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_68d77.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_68d77.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.17\Modules\CMakeCCompilerABI.c"

  cmTC_68d77.vcxproj -> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_68d77.exe




Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Garbage Collector/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_5a8e5.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.26.28806 for x64

  testCXXCompiler.cxx

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_5a8e5.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_5a8e5.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx"

  cmTC_5a8e5.vcxproj -> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_5a8e5.exe




Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Garbage Collector/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_2e3ba.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.26.28806 for x64

  CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_2e3ba.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_2e3ba.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.17\Modules\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp"

  cmTC_2e3ba.vcxproj -> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_2e3ba.exe
```

and the console says:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDeterminemain.cppCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Garbage Collector/build/CMakeFiles/3.17.3/CMakemain.cppCompiler.cmake
CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  No CMAKE_main.cpp_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakemain.cppInformation.cmake
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Garbage Collector/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Garbage Collector\build>cmake --build .
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

If you have an idea how to fix this, please tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see your `tests/CMakeLists.txt`, but is seems you pass `main.cpp` as the **language** argument to the `project()` call.

Comment: Thank you so much!